# File name truncation in java.io.File(String) if the file name contains '#'

Tags: java, file-io

I am trying to create a new file using java.io.File(String). If the filepath string contains '#' symbol means, created file's name gets truncated. Please anyone explain me why it's happening and how to create the filename with '#' from java.

My code.

```
new File("d:\\file#test.xml");
```

Expected output:

```
file#test.xml
```

Real output:

```
file
```

Note: I need to create the file in both windows and Unix file system.

Normally both windows and Unix systems are allowed to create a filename with #.

**Edited:**

Thanks to all your reply. yes, problem is not in java.io.File(String). Actually i am getting this problem when i am trying to create the xml file using xml transformer.

please find the full code below.

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;

import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;

import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;

import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;

import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;

import org.w3c.dom.Element;

import org.w3c.dom.Node;


public class XMLWriterDOM {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    DocumentBuilder dBuilder;

    try {

        dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document doc = dBuilder.newDocument();

        //add elements to Document

        Element rootElement =

            doc.createElementNS("http://www.journaldev.com/employee", "Employees");

        //append root element to document

        doc.appendChild(rootElement);



        //append first child element to root element

        rootElement.appendChild(getEmployee(doc, "1", "Pankaj", "29", "Java Developer", "Male"));



        //for output to file, 

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();

        //for pretty print

        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);




        StreamResult file = new StreamResult(new File("d:\\\\emps#1.xml"));



        //write data



        transformer.transform(source, file);

        System.out.println("DONE");



    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}





private static Node getEmployee(Document doc, String id, String name, String age, String role,

        String gender) {

    Element employee = doc.createElement("Employee");



    //set id attribute

    employee.setAttribute("id", id);



    //create name element

    employee.appendChild(getEmployeeElements(doc, employee, "name", name));



    //create age element

    employee.appendChild(getEmployeeElements(doc, employee, "age", age));



    //create role element

    employee.appendChild(getEmployeeElements(doc, employee, "role", role));



    //create gender element

    employee.appendChild(getEmployeeElements(doc, employee, "gender", gender));



    return employee;

}





//utility method to create text node

private static Node getEmployeeElements(Document doc, Element element, String name, String value) {

    Element node = doc.createElement(name);

    node.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(value));

    return node;

}



}
```

Please suggest me to solve this issue.

Comment: I tried in windows its working

Comment: First of all, escape that backslash: `new File("d:\\file#test.xml");` (or use `new File("d:", "file#test.xml")`). And it is working fine to create files with `#`. Your problem seems to be somewhere else.

Comment: pz share ur code to get the real problem !

Comment: Maybe you should check the File.java source code. There is path normalization step : this.path = fs.normalize(pathname); which on unix allows the # in the file name. Since I do not have access to windows machine so cannot comment on Windows implementation.

Comment: Works for me on Windows too...

Comment: yes it does. I'm not sure whether he is calling `File.crateNewFile` or not !

Comment: i have added the full code in Edited section of the post. please look that and help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem under Mac OS X.

```
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String temp = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
        Path path = Paths.get(temp, "foo#bar.txt");
        System.out.println(path.toAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
/var/folders/qm/0t0z2hfx6lb53gf7d8h2srzm0000gp/T/foo#bar.txt
```

What is the code that makes the output?